# First order logic and conjective normal form

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

Consider the following paragraph and please answer these questions below

“Anyone who eats junk food or drink carbonated beverages will be a cancer victim. It is not the case that some people eat junk food but they are healthy. Every cancer victims are not healthy. Bimal is a healthy person”

Write the above paragraph in first order logic and convert them in to the conjunctive normal form. By considering the paragraph in Part(d) check whether Bimal drink carbonated beverages.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

For the first sentence:

[image: \forall x,y,z Person(x) \land JunkFood(y) \land CarbonatedBeverage(z) \land (eat(x,y) \lor drink(x,z)) \implies CancerVictim(x)]

For the second senctence:

[image: \lnot [\forall y \exists x JunkFood(y) \land Person(x) \land eat(x,y) \land Healthy(x)]]

For the third sentence:

[image: \forall x Person(x) \land CancerVictim(x) \implies \neg Healthy(x)]

For the fourth sentence:

[image: Healthy(Bimal)]

---

To turn into CNF first you should remove the universal quantifiers and replace the existential quantifiers with skolem variables:

- [image: Person(x) \land JunkFood(y) \land CarbonatedBeverage(z) \land (eat(x,y) \lor drink(x,z)) \implies CancerVictim(x)]
- [image: \lnot [\exists x JunkFood(y) \land Person(x) \land eat(x,y) \land Healthy(x)]]

[image: \equiv \forall x \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg Person(x) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor \neg Healthy(x)]

[image: \equiv \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg Person(x) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor \neg Healthy(x)]

- [image: Person(x) \land CancerVictim(x) \implies \neg Healthy(x)]
- [image: Healthy(Bimal)]

---

Now you can use logic rules to turn it into CNF.

#### first senctence:

[image: \lnot [Person(x) \land JunkFood(y) \land CarbonatedBeverage(z) \land (eat(x,y) \lor drink(x,z))] \lor CancerVictim(x)]

[image: \equiv \neg Person(x) \lor \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg CarbonatedBeverage(z) \lor (\neg eat(x,y) \land \neg drink(x,z)) \lor CancerVictim(x)]

[image: \equiv [\neg Person(x) \lor \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg CarbonatedBeverage(z) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor CancerVictim(x)] \land [\neg Person(x) \lor \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg CarbonatedBeverage(z) \lor \neg drink(x,z) \lor CancerVictim(x)]]

[image: \equiv [\neg Person(x) \lor \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor CancerVictim(x)] \land [\neg Person(x) \lor \neg CarbonatedBeverage(z) \lor \neg drink(x,z) \lor CancerVictim(x)]]

I removed predicates from the irrelevant variable scopes (junkFood and CarbonatedBeverage). You can also do this at the beginning by having two universal quantifiers, one for food and one for drink.

#### second sentence:

[image: \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg Person(x) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor \neg Healthy(x)]

#### third sentence:

[image: Person(x) \land CancerVictim(x) \implies \neg Healthy(x)]

[image: \equiv \neg[Person(x) \land CancerVictim(x)] \lor \neg Healthy(x)]

[image: \equiv \neg Person(x) \lor \neg CancerVictim(x) \lor \neg Healthy(x)]

#### fourth sentence:

[image: Healthy(Bimal)]

---

Now try to remove the corresponding sentences. We assume Bimal drinks carbonated beverages:

[image: \exists x CarbonatedBeverage(x) \land drink(Bimal,x)]

[image: \equiv CarbonatedBeverage(f(x)) \land drink(Bimal,f(x))]

and we know:
[image: Person(Bimal)]

So now we have these sentences as CNF clauses:

1. [image: \neg Person(x) \lor \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor CancerVictim(x)]
2. [image: \neg Person(x) \lor \neg CarbonatedBeverage(z) \lor \neg drink(x,z) \lor CancerVictim(x)]
3. [image: \neg JunkFood(y) \lor \neg Person(x) \lor \neg eat(x,y) \lor \neg Healthy(x)]
4. [image: \neg Person(x) \lor \neg CancerVictim(x) \lor \neg Healthy(x)]
5. [image: Healthy(Bimal)]
6. [image: Person(Bimal)]
7. [image: CarbonatedBeverage(f(x))]
8. [image: drink(Bimal,f(x))]

and we are trying to find a contradiction:

- from 4,5,6: [image: CancerVictim(Bimal)]
- from 2,6,7,8: [image: \neg CancerVictim(Bimal)]

Since these two contradict, we get to an empty clause and according to reduction to the absurd we can say our initial assumption (Bimal drinks carbonated beverages) is wrong.

Comment: Thank you soo much where can I study these logic please give me website to srudy

Comment: @SmkSon you can study **Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach** book chapters 8 and 9, but [this pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiRssrY8ITjAhXCmOAKHddgB5cQFjABegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cornell.edu%2Fcourses%2Fcs4700%2F2011fa%2Flectures%2F16_FirstOrderLogic.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0iaqSFe1W5HtwK9VWtlVW5) also has a good example at the end. Check my answer, if it is right accept it, otherwise correct me.